# multiple parents in router for a view

Tags: view, router

i need have multiple parents for a view, for example:

- view products list of all products with links to single product
- view categories list of all categoires with links to single category
- View category with inside the list of products of category with link to single product

i want this urls:

https://namesite.com/productscategeories/
index.php?option=com_mycomp&view=categories (i can set a menu item)

https://namesite.com/productscategeories/singlecategoryname
--> index.php?option=com_mycomp&view=category&id=2

https://namesite.com/productscategeories/singlecategoryname/single_product_name -->
index.php?option=com_mycomp&view=product&id=6&categoryid=2

https://namesite.com/products/ (i can set a menu item) -->
index.php?option=com_mycomp&view=products

index.php?option=com_mycomp&view=product&id=6-->
https://namesite.com/products/single_product_name

But, in router i can set a single parent like

```
$ccProduct->setKey('id')->setParent($products);
```

so product view under category go to view under products

in my router.php i have:

```
$products = new RouterViewConfiguration('products');
        $this->registerView($products);
        $ccProduct = new RouterViewConfiguration('product');
        $ccProduct->setKey('id')->setParent($products);
        $this->registerView($ccProduct);
```

but i want add more parents for a view, how i can make it?

thanks for help

Comment: Someone here is looking for the same solution, but according to this ticket it is not possible yet in Joomla 4. : https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/39974